How to Safely Share and Validate API Gateway JsonSchema Between CDK and Lambda in a TypeScript Monorepo?
I use TypeScript in my project, which is organized as a monorepo with two main directories:

infrastructure: Contains all the CDK code.
lambda: Contains the handlers for each Lambda function.

The CDK code dynamically reads the file system to discover and configure the Lambdas in the lambda directory, setting up all the necessary infrastructure accordingly.
Problem:
For body validation using API Gateway, I need to use JsonSchema from the CDK package. However, I can't directly use CDK as a dependency in the lambda directory. Initially, I redefined the JsonSchema type in the lambda directory. When using the exported model from the lambda directory in the CDK, I just cast it to JsonSchema.
The issue with this approach is that if the JsonSchema interface in the CDK package is updated, my redefined type in the lambda directory won't reflect those changes, potentially causing issues that go unnoticed.
Considered Solution:
I thought about exporting the JsonSchema interface after importing it in the CDK (under the infrastructure directory) and then importing it again under the lambda directory. This way, I can ensure consistency without redefining the interface.
However, I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. Specifically:

Will this approach work as intended?
Will importing JsonSchema from the infrastructure directory into the lambda directory only import the interface, or will it also include the entire CDK package?

Note: My goal is to always keep my lambda function as lightweight as possible
Example Code:
infrastructure/schema.ts
import { JsonSchema } from 'cdk-package';
export { JsonSchema };

*lambda/handler.ts*   

import { JsonSchema } from '../infrastructure/schema';

// Use JsonSchema for validation in Lambda handler
const schema: JsonSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    id: { type: 'string' },
    name: { type: 'string' },
  },
  required: ['id', 'name'],
};



